# How to append an array on textfield in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an application in which I want to fetch content from a database using a particular ID column and later display all that content in textfields on a button press. The snippet below shows how I fetch the content in an array.

```
//this is a function which i am created which will be called in button click event  
-(NSArray*)getStudents 
{ 
    NSMutableArray *studentArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil; 
    NSString *query=@"select * from UserInformation where UserId=?"; 
    const char *sql = [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
            Student *newStudent=[[Student alloc]init]; 
            newStudent.age=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0); 
            newStudent.name=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]; 
            [studentArray addObject:newStudent]; 
        } 
    } 

    return studentArray; 
}
```

I have a problem adding this array to my textfields so that when I click on the button my textfields are loaded with the values from the database for a particular `userid`. I have written the above function in one of my controllers and my textfields are defined in another controller. How do I fill the above array in my textfields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe below as reference code ..

```
//Get all your student object from database
NSArray* myArray = [self getStudents ];
//Use mutable string to append all the data in single string.
NSMutableString* stringName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

//Traverse through the Student array 
for(id arrayObj in myArray)
{
  Student* student = (Student*)arrayObj; 
  [stringName appendString:student.name];
  [stringName appendString:@" ";
}

//Now you have stringName variable holding all the student name and this is space      separated  string 
myTextField.text = stringName;
```

Comment: @Rani you did change `appenString` to `appendString` right? And do you want to show them in multiple text fields or a single text field?

Comment: Where should i call this code in the button click event method because my textfields are in another controller clas

Comment: @deepak ya i changed it to appendString & i want to show in multiple textfields

Comment: @Rani :each name in different textView Right ?

Comment: ya different name in different textfields which comes from the corresponding sqlite database column values